# Open Word with params and takspan addin open

Tags: ms-word, office-js

Is it possible to open Word with parameters, with a taskpane addin open and where I can use those parameters in the addin. So two questions:

- Can you open Word with parameters, or create a Word document with parameters programatically, where these parameters are accessible for the Word addin?
- Can you automatically open a Word taskpane addin? E.g. using a certain template?

I'm asking because of the following scenario:
Client is working in their in-house developed ERP application. They open some customer information and want to start Word. It would be nice if the addin somehow receives the context of the chosen customer from the ERP system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure I understood the question:  it sounds like you have some sort of a web (or other content-management) system where, when you click "download", you'd like to have an add-in already pre-inserted, and with some context passed in?

This should be within the realm of doable.  You can add a new taskpane to a document via the OpenXML SDK. The simplest way is probably to just create a document with the Office Add-in inserted within it, then run a tool that will analyze your document and generate the C# code you need to re-create such document. Please see http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/04/open-xml-sdk-tool-to-analyse-documents-and-generated-c-code/, for a blog post that describes the process. The tool itself is available at https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=30425.

Passing in a context should be a fairly similar process, where -- using the same OpenXML SDK -- you would add a Settings entry for the Add-in.  Hope this helps!

Comment: This really does help, didn't expect that this was doable. Thanks very much.

Comment: in addition to above, you can also insert CustomXMlParts with the state you need into  the document (at the same time you inject the task pane add-in with the XMLSdk) and then you can retrieve the customXMLparts with the Word JAvaScript API API  here is a sample https://github.com/OfficeDev/Word-Add-in-Work-with-custom-XML-parts